# Changing the cache time in jquery

Tags: ajax, json, caching, jquery

if we pass `true` for `cache` in `$.ajax()` the jquery will cache the loaded data,
I want to know is there any way to change the cache time for `$.ajax()` ?
for example if ajax requested in 10 minutes the jquery load previous data but if requested after 10 minutes load fresh data.

UPDATE :

We need cache the JSON data, so I should use Ajax in JSON datatype

Comment: Set the cache headers on the server for 10 minutes.

Comment: There seems to be some vital information missing from this question by reading Vincent's answer. It seems you are making an AJAX call on an HTML resource and expecting the result as JSON \-:

Answer (score 7):

jQuery doesn't actually cache the requests for you - when you set `cache` to `false`, it simply sets some headers and passes a "cache buster" query string variable (e.g., `?_=487262189472`) to prevent the browser or any proxies from returning a cached response.

If you want 10 minute caching, you could implement your own fairly easily.  E.g.,

```
var cacheBuster = new Date().getTime();
setInterval(function() {
    cacheBuster = new Date().getTime();
}, 1000 * 60 * 10)
```

Then simply add that in a query string variable to your requests (e.g., `?_noCache=<cacheBuster>`).

---

Edit: for the sake of making this a more complete solution, here's an example of how you can use the `cacheBuster` on all jQuery Ajax requests transparently to the actual Ajax call:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
    var startChar = options.url.indexOf('?') === -1 ? '?' : '&';
    options.url += startChar + '_noCache=' + cacheBuster;
});
```

Comment: Do you know of cases in which wouldn't really work and will still fetch a new request to the server?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like an ideal playground for leveraging jQuery's Deferred object.

There's a great article by Addy Osmani and Julian Aubourg on MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg723713.aspx

in short, they have an example there that explains how they cache requests, this request in particular will be cached forever.

```
var cachedPromises = {};

$.getCachedURL = function( url, callback ) {
    if ( !cachedPromises[ url ] ) {
        cachedPromises[ url ] = $.Deferred(function( defer ) {
            $.get( url ).then( defer.resolve, defer.reject );
        }).promise();
    }
    return cachedPromises[ url ].done( callback );
};
```

and then resolve the Deferred as such

```
$.getCachedURL( url ).then( successCallback, errorCallback );
```

so if you want certain urls to be cached for only a certain time we can modify the existing code and do something along the lines of (note that this is off the top of my head)

```
var cachedPromises = {};
var cachedTimeouts = {};

$.getCachedURL = function( url, callback, cacheTime) {
    if ( !cachedPromises[ url ] ) {
        cachedPromises[ url ] = $.Deferred(function( defer ) {
            $.get( url ).then( defer.resolve, defer.reject );
        }).promise();
        cachedTimeouts[ url ] = setTimeout(function () {
            clearTimeout(cachedTimeouts[ url ]);
            delete cachedPromises[ url ];
        }, cacheTime);
    }
    return cachedPromises[ url ].done( callback );
};
```

and using a callback:

```
var callback = function () {
    console.log('callback', arguments)
}

var cacheTime = 3600;

$.getCachedURL('/dynamic/config', callback, cacheTime).then(function ()
{
    console.log('success', arguments)
}, function ()
{
    console.log('error', arguments)
});
```

where callback will return the traditional jQuery ajax succes/error arguments `data`, `textStatus` and `jqXHR`

if you want JSON use `$.getJSON` instead of `$.get`

```
$.get( url ).then( defer.resolve, defer.reject );
$.getJSON( url ).then( defer.resolve, defer.reject );
```

note that you could still just use `$.ajax`

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
}).then( defer.resolve, defer.reject );
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to get JSON data, this function don't pass JSON data to my callback

Comment: I updated my answer with an additional example that show you how and what gets passed back. I fixed some syntax as well so please copy the example again.

Comment: thanks, the arguments in callback is HTML, we need JSON, I think we should change the `$.getCachedURL` function

Comment: That last is not clear from your question so I consider I have answered your question to the best of my efforts. If you need more information either accept this answer or update your question above as to be helpful for others.

Comment: I added needed dataType to my question

Comment: I don't understand, you either return your response as JSON or HTML or XML or JSONP, but jQuery won't automagically convert HTML to JSON.